# How can you use Android Room in an app with several activities?

Tags: android, android-room

I'm sorry if the question seems too obvious, but I'm quite new to Android, and all the tutorials that I see to learn how to use Room show apps with only one activity. How can you do it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: "and all the tutorials that I see to learn how to use Room show apps with only one activity" -- modern Android app development tends to use fewer activities, with fragments or composables for the screens. FWIW, [this free book of mine](https://commonsware.com/AndExplore) walks you through building a Room-based app with three screens. It generally follows [Google's recommended app architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture), where your database access is managed by a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, you get get an instance of the @Database annotated class. Frequently this will be singleton.

Here's an example/demo hijacked from an existing project.

The @Entity class (just the one for simplicity) **UserEntity**

```
@Entity
data class UserEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) val user: String,
    val lastMessage: String,
    val lastTime: String
)
```

- nothing special about this

An @Dao annotated class that caters for insertions and extraction of data **AllDAO**

```
@Dao
interface AllDAO {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertUser(entity: UserEntity)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM userentity")
    fun getAllUsers(): List<UserEntity>

}
```

The @Database annotated class that has a basic singleton approach **TheDatabase**

```
@Database(entities = [UserEntity::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAO(): AllDAO

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

- so the getInstance function will return the same instance throughout.
- the first time it is invoked it instantiates the instance variable *(note that just getting the instance doesn't actually open the database, this is not done until the database itself is accessed, if the database does not already exists then it will be created along with the tables)*
- `.allowMainThreadQueries` has been used for convenience and brevity

And here's two activities **MainActivity** and **OtherActivity** that use the database.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAO
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAO()
        dao.insertUser(UserEntity("Fred","1st Fred","0000"))
        dao.insertUser(UserEntity("Mary","1st Mary","1111"))
        dao.insertUser(UserEntity("Jane","1st Jane","2222"))
        logAllUsers("_RUN1")
        dao.insertUser(UserEntity("Fred","2nd Fred","4444"))
        dao.insertUser(UserEntity("Mary","2nd Mary","5555"))
        dao.insertUser(UserEntity("Jane","2nd Jane","6666"))
        logAllUsers("_RUN2")

        var intent = Intent(this,OtherActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    }
        fun logAllUsers(prefix: String) {
            for (u in dao.getAllUsers()) {
                Log.d("USERINFO${prefix}","User is ${u.user} Last Message is ${u.lastMessage} LastTime is ${u.lastTime}")
            }
        }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.d("RESUMED","Activity has been resumed")
    }
}
```

- this

  - inserts some rows (3),
  - extracts all the rows (3) outputting them to the log,
  - inserts another 3 rows THAT REPLACE the first 3 rows due to the primary key values being the same for the 2nd set
  - extracts all the rows (3) outputting them to the log
  - starts the OtherActivity
  - writes a line to the log when the MainActivity is resumed (when OtherActivity is finished)

and **OtherActivity** :-

```
class OtherActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAO
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_other)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAO()

        for (u in dao.getAllUsers()) {
            Log.d("OAINFO","User is ${u.user} LastTime is ${u.lastTime} Message is ${u.lastMessage}")
        }
        finish() /* back to invoking activity */
    }
}
```

This :-

- extracts all the rows (3) and then finishes passing control back to MainActivity
- as can be seen exactly the same method is used to get an instance of the @Database annotated class and the @Dao annotated class instance

The result in the log being :-

```
2022-04-29 09:14:47.134 D/USERINFO_RUN1: User is Fred Last Message is 1st Fred LastTime is 0000
2022-04-29 09:14:47.134 D/USERINFO_RUN1: User is Mary Last Message is 1st Mary LastTime is 1111
2022-04-29 09:14:47.134 D/USERINFO_RUN1: User is Jane Last Message is 1st Jane LastTime is 2222


2022-04-29 09:14:47.141 D/USERINFO_RUN2: User is Fred Last Message is 2nd Fred LastTime is 4444
2022-04-29 09:14:47.141 D/USERINFO_RUN2: User is Mary Last Message is 2nd Mary LastTime is 5555
2022-04-29 09:14:47.141 D/USERINFO_RUN2: User is Jane Last Message is 2nd Jane LastTime is 6666

2022-04-29 09:14:47.380 D/OAINFO: User is Fred LastTime is 4444 Message is 2nd Fred
2022-04-29 09:14:47.380 D/OAINFO: User is Mary LastTime is 5555 Message is 2nd Mary
2022-04-29 09:14:47.380 D/OAINFO: User is Jane LastTime is 6666 Message is 2nd Jane

2022-04-29 09:14:47.154 D/RESUMED: Activity has been resumed
```